# Eigenvalues of limits problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

we consider the problem 
$$
\begin{cases}
y''+2y'+\lambda y=0\\
y'(0)=y(1)=0
\end{cases}
$$
The question is to prouve that this problem admits eigenvalues $\lambda >1$.

I try to do the following: we put $\lambda-1=\alpha^2$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^\star_+$. Then, the general solution of the differential equation is 
$$
y(x)= e^{-x}[C_1 \cos(\alpha x) + C_2 \sin(\alpha x)]
$$
Then using the limis conditions, we have:
$$
y(1)=0=> C_1 \cos(\alpha) + C_2 \sin(\alpha)=0
$$
and
$$
y'(0)=0 => C_1 = \alpha C_2
$$
Then combined the two, we obtaine 
$$
C_2 (\alpha \cos(\alpha)+ \sin(\alpha))=0
$$
Is it true? Please. And finally who's the eigenvalues of this problem? Please

Comment: Any solutions of $α=-\tan(α)$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917846/fixed-point-iteration-for-x-tanx, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305538/numerical-solution-to-x-tan-x

Comment: But why we can divide on $\cos(\alpha)$? What about the case$ \cos(\alpha)=0$?

Comment: Then $α\ne 0$ and $\sin α=\pm 1$, so the original term is not zero.

Comment: Ok , i understand. So my solution is absolutly correct? Please

Comment: Yes, there is a solution between any two poles of the tangent function. More precisely, set $α=a+u$, $a=(k-\frac12)\pi$, $k=1,2,3,…$ then $(a+u)\tan(u)=1$ has a solution close to $(a+\frac4{3a})^{-1}$ for larger $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good so far. Your question is whether it's possible that $\lambda>1$ is a solution, equivalently $\alpha^2>0$. The nontrivial solution necessarily needs $C_1,C_2\neq 0$ (if one is 0 so is the other from your results). Thus $\alpha\cos(\alpha)+\sin(\alpha)=0$. At $\alpha=\pi/2$, the l.h.s. is $1$. At $\alpha=\pi$, the l.h.s. is $-\pi$, so there is a solution $\alpha \in(\pi/2,\pi)$.

Comment: So my solution is correct?! But i don't understant who's $\alpha$. Can you give me more details please

Comment: ...You defined $\alpha^2=\lambda-1$, right?

Comment: yes i know this, but $\alpha$ is solution of the equation $\alpha=- tan \alpha$. This is right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thak you so much